# pyodbc Azure transient error

Tags: python-3.x, azure, pyodbc, transient

My script is listed below:

```
 import pyodbc
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver,
                         server=server,
                         user=username,
                         database=database,
                         Trusted_Connection='yes', 
                         autocommit = True)
```

However, I got error message:

```
('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant encountered an error that might not occur if retried. Possible reasons include a transient network error. [x80048849].  (-2147186615) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Anyone has idea? My error came out when I tried to connect to azure. In the error message, it said **retried** may work, but I have tried several times, and I still saw this error. I see most of people have this issue when they run the query. Please feel free to leave your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. Because it is connected to Azure, i dont need to include **Trusted_Connection='yes'**, which is for windows authentication.